What do symmetric 2-qubits gates look like?
A gate $U= (u_{ij})_{i,j= 1}^4$ is symmetric if the action of the gate is the same as the action of $Swap\ U\ Swap$ where the swap gate is $$Swap= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then computing gives $Swap\ U\ Swap= Swap\ \begin{pmatrix} u_{11} & u_{13} & u_{12} & u_{14} \\
u_{21} & u_{23} & u_{22} & u_{24} \\
u_{31} & u_{33} & u_{32} & u_{34} \\
u_{41} & u_{43} & u_{42} & u_{44} \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} u_{11} & u_{13} & u_{12} & u_{14} \\
u_{31} & u_{33} & u_{32} & u_{34} \\
u_{21} & u_{23} & u_{22} & u_{24} \\
u_{41} & u_{43} & u_{42} & u_{44} \end{pmatrix}$
and the two matrices are equal exactly when $u_{13}= u_{12},\ u_{43}= u_{42},\ u_{31}= u_{21},\ u_{33}= u_{22},\ u_{32}= u_{23},\ u_{34}= u_{24}$, which completely characterizes symmetric gates to be of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} u_{11} & a & a & u_{14}\\
d & b & c & e\\
d & c & b & e\\
u_{41} & f & f & u_{44} \end{pmatrix}$$
This also tells us that a controlled-U is symmetric exactly when that $U$ is a Phase gate $P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\
0 & e^{i\lambda}\end{pmatrix}$
Is this correct or am I missing something?
I wonder if there are known symmetric gates which are implemented in the existing hardware (in IBM Qiskit) besides the controlled-P (CZ being under this case).

It might be interesting to generalize this to $n$-qubits gates.

I think I heard that some ion based computers use Square-Root-of-SWAP gates as their native two-qubit entangling gate.

When you're talking about the generalization to $n$-qubit gates, what are you interested in? Since the gate is still controlled by a single submit, what would be the SWAP operation here? Or would you control on another $n$-qubit register being in state $|1\cdots1\rangle$?

Any gate of the form $ g \otimes g $ for $ g  \in U(2) $ is symmetric. And as you point out a controlled phase gate is  symmetric. My guess would be that the non-entangling gates $ g \otimes g $ together with the controlled phase gates  and the SWAP gate probably generates the group you describe above (the centralizer of the SWAP gate).

By generalizing to n qubits, I mean a gate which is insensible to any permutation of the n qubits.

You might want to look for Permutation Invariant/Equivariant Quantum Circuits.
